# Azure api: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format. HeaderName: Content-Length

Tags: azure, azure-functions, postman

I am trying to call azure API "put range" function with postman.
I get result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:b131385d-301a-0044-31fd-344678000000
Time:2020-05-28T14:35:45.0769047Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>9</HeaderValue>
</Error>
```

My request has these headers:

```
x-ms-write:Update
Range:bytes=0-3
Content-Length:9
```

Body includes:

> some text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, your `Range` header has only 4 bytes (0 - 3) however your content length is actually 9 bytes. This is probably the reason why you're getting this error.

Please change your `Range` header so that it sends 9 bytes.

`Range:bytes=0-8`

Or change your content length header to send only 4 bytes.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem. After I fixed this I was getting error:
`"The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource."`  
  
I resolved this by first calling [set file properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-file-properties) function and setting the file length from 0 to the length I need.

Comment: While this fixed the problem but I believe it is an incorrect approach. When you create a file, you need to specify the size. Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file.

Comment: You are right. The correct process is Create File -> Put Range